# Multiple tables how to fetch data in single query

Tags: java

```
SELECT
     tbl_category.`cat_name` AS tbl_category_cat_name,
     registration.`firm_name` AS registration_firm_name,
     tbl_prod.`prod_name` AS tbl_prod_prod_name,
     tbl_prod.`prod_desc` AS tbl_prod_prod_desc,
     tbl_prod.`prod_size` AS tbl_prod_prod_size,
     tbl_prod.`prod_prate` AS tbl_prod_prod_prate,
     tbl_prod.`prod_mrp` AS tbl_prod_prod_mrp,
     tbl_prod.`prod_srate` AS tbl_prod_prod_srate,
     tbl_unit.`unit` AS tbl_unit_unit,
     tbl_brand.`bnd_name` AS tbl_brand_bnd_name
FROM
     `tbl_category` tbl_category,
     `registration` registration,
     `tbl_prod` tbl_prod,
     `tbl_unit` tbl_unit,
     `tbl_brand` tbl_brand
```

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: Beyond that: you want other people to spend their time to help you with your problem. So you please spend the time required to properly format/indent your question. Instead of dumping such content on other people.

Comment: use sql joins to get required values from multiple tables.

Comment: Mention the relationship between these tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sql Join.Check this following link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/joining-three-tables-sql/

Eg:

```
SELECT e.employeename
, e.employeeid
, e.employeedesc
, a.address
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN native nt
on e.employeeid = nt.studentid
INNER JOIN address a
  on nt.addressid = a.addressid
```